# Any JDBC Driver for Google BigQuery Standard SQL

Tags: jdbc, google-bigquery

I need a JDBC driver to connect my application to Google BigQuery. I tried CData JDBC driver, but it did not support all types of Standard SQL queries. Are there any other complete options?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The official [JDBC driver for BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/partners/simba-drivers/) should support all types of standard SQL queries.

Comment: I have another querstion. In Simba configuration, I should set the url in this format:   " jdbc:bigquery://[Host]:[Port];ProjectId=[Project];OAuthType=
[AuthValue];[Property1]=[Value1];[Property2]=[Value2]; "  I don't know what I should set for Host. My data is on Google bigquery, what is my server ip though?

Comment: You need to specify `https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2` as the host. The Install and Configuration Guide that comes with the driver has an example of `jdbc:bigquery://https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2:443;ProjectId=MyBigQueryProject;OAuthType=1;` as a complete connection URL.

Comment: I still cannot connect to my Google Bigquery dataset via Simba. I want to connect from R application using RJDBC package. library(RJDBC)

driver <- JDBC(driverClass = "com.simba.googlebigquery.jdbc42.Driver", classPath = "~/JDBC/GoogleBigQueryJDBC42.jar", identifier.quote = "'")

conn <- dbConnect(driver,"jdbc:bigquery://https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2:443;ProjectId=My_project_Id;OAuthType=1;")

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with R to help, unfortunately. Let's see if someone else answers the new question that you posted, though.

Answer (score 1):

> Are there any other complete options?

You can use Query Prefix `#standardSQL` to force use of Standard SQL

See more details in [Setting a query prefix](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/enabling-standard-sql#sql-prefix)

Comment: what about JDBC driver? Do you know any?

Comment: see Elliott's answer for driver. In case if you still will have some issues with it  - Query Prefix can help :o)