# Is it possible to deploy a JDBC connector in Google Big Query?

Tags: jdbc, deployment, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, connector

I was wondering how I can deploy a JDBC connector in Google Big Query/Google Cloud. 
Or is it even possible to do ?

So far, I didn't find any information on the internet nor in the Google Big Query documentation. 
Feel free to provide me any links.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Any JDBC Driver for Google BigQuery Standard SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40538737/any-jdbc-driver-for-google-bigquery-standard-sql)

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you're really asking "how to connect to BigQuery using JDBC", you can download the official BigQuery JDBC drivers from Google's site:

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/providers/simba-drivers/

You'll then need to deploy that driver wherever your application is running e.g. a GCP Compute instance.

You cannot deploy anything "in" BigQuery itself as it's a managed service.